# Multiple File Upload with ajax in IE

Tags: php, jquery, upload, multipart

I know IE doesn't support multiple file upload so I've been using jQuery (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It works in firefox and chrome but not in IE. It doesn't seem to access the php file at all. So I made this test to try it out but nothing ever gets printed out. It seems to get stuck somewhere. Any advice?

HTML:

```
<form id='form' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="file[]" type="file"/>               
   <input name="file[]" type="file"/>               
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#form').ajaxSubmit({
   url: "ajax.php",
   success : onUploadComplete,
   data: data
});
```

callback:

```
function onUploadComplete(result) {
   console.log(result)
}
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
    exit("HERE");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this resource to:

[Getting jQuery Media Plugin to work in IE9](http://code.adonline.id.au/jquery-media-plugin-ie9/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource. I have used this code across all browsers and all you will lose with IE is the drag/drop. Very robust resource and easy to implement.

[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: The problem with this is that only need the user to upload 2 files. One is an image and one is an audio file. And they're being uploaded for different reasons. Basically I need separate uploaders but share the same submit like this:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress3.html